# Correlation Syntax for R

Tags: r, syntax, correlation

Very basic question, it's my first time writing syntax in R. Trying to write basic correlation syntax. Hypothesis is as follows: X1 (Predictor variable) and X2 (latent predictor variable) will be positively associated with Y (outcome variable), over and above X3 (latent predictor variable). How can I write this in R?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your statistics chops are, but pure the correlation as measured by the r-squared value will strictly increase with added variables to your model. So, if these variables are stored in data frame `df`,

```
model_full <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = df)
```

fits the full model. Use `summary(model_full)` to view summary statistics of the model.

```
model_reduced <- lm(Y ~ X3, data = df)
```

fits the reduced model. Here's where the more complicated stuff comes in. To test the value of `X1` and `X2`, you probably want an [F-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test) to test whether the coefficients on `X1` and `X2` are jointly statistically significantly different from zero (this is how I interpret 'above and beyond `X3`'). To compute that test, use

```
lmtest::waldtest(model_full, model_reduced, test = "F")
```

Hope this helps!